# program hangs while sending serial data in VxWorks

Tags: c++, serial-port, vxworks

I'm communicating with a Automatic Land Navigation System via serial wherein I'll be issuing commands to it and will get in return the required response from it. Since the messages are terminated by \r\n just like in GPS (NMEA standard) I'm opening the serial port in Line Mode. The problem I'm facing is if I try to send data at a faster rate the program is getting hanged. For time being I'm flushing both the input and output buffers as a workaround of this issue. Does anybody have a better solution. This is how I'm opening my serial port:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sioLib.h>
#include <tyLib.h>

int fd = -1;

void recvthread() {
    fd = open("/tyCo/2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY, 0);

    if (fd != -1) {
        int nRes = ioctl(fd, FIOBAUDRATE, 9600);
        if (nRes == -1)
            perror("Error in setting Baudrate for /tyCo/2");

        int options = ioctl(fd, FIOGETOPTIONS, 0);
        if (options == -1)
            options = 0;

        options |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
        options &= ~CSIZE;
        options |= CS8;
        options &= ~STOPB;
        options &= ~PARENB;
        options |= OPT_LINE;

        nRes = ioctl(fd, FIOSETOPTIONS, options);
        if (nRes == -1)
            perror("Error in setting options for /tyCo/2");

        char buff[512];
        while (true) {
            // receive data
            int len = read(fd, buff, 10);

            // process the received data
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    std::thread t(recvthread);

    sleep(5);
    char buff[512];
    while (true) {
        int len = write(fd, buff, 56);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250LL));
    }
}
```

I use Curtiss Wright 185 board which has xmc 371 serial card as an accessory for which I use tews serial driver.

Comment: Is the program source written in the article equivalent to the actual situation? It looks like the write process that issues the command is taking place at no time interval. Isn't it necessary to sleep or wait for a timer notification in a while loop?

Comment: @kunif You can assume a gap of 250 milliseconds between successive `write` calls

Comment: Isn't the interval too short? Why not try increasing the interval? Or do you always need to get the information? For example, is there a mode in which notification is given only when there is a change? Please try various things.

Comment: @kunif but I'm not understanding the reason behind this hanging behavior?

Comment: In order to understand it, it is necessary to understand the specifications of the CPU board and device driver running VxWorks, and the communication and command/response specifications of the connected device. And if you want advice or answers, you'll need to present them in your question article.

Comment: Since there is no information on the target device, the following possibilities are generally considered. As I commented earlier, the command issuance interval is too short. Inappropriate processing of received data (eg, taking too long / including waiting for another I/O or result of another subsystem). The device driver buffer size settings and flow control settings are not appropriate.

Comment: You can use ioctl() with FIONREAD to check if data has been received. Keep in mind then a serial interface is created, there is a buffer of 512 bytes created for each TX/RX channels. read/write operation are using these buffers. The serial drivers will get/put serial date through these buffers. In addition, make sure that VX_FP_TASK is set for the task running main() function.

Comment: @Jean-Jacques can we set any option that can override the older data inside these buffers to prevent buffer overflow? This option might be handy if there is no receiver but only sender which keeps on sending data periodically.

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can only empty with the FIOFLUSH, FIORFLUSH or FIOWFLUSH